# Error: Could not find or load main class IntelliJ MacOs

Tags: java, macos, gradle, libgdx

I have googled and searched for solutions on the internet for days but nothing works. When running the DesktopLauncher class with the main()-method of my Libgdx project, I always get the same error: `Error: Could not find or load main class`

I am working on a Libgdx project together with friends.  All on the same project through git. Some information: Im using macOS 10.14.2 and IntelliJ, all my friends are working on windows, which Im thinking might have something to do with the problem, because for them, everything is working fine. Its a java project using Gradle. Im using jdk1.8.0_191. Building the Gradle Project is not a problem, but running the DesktopLauncher class always brings the same error as you can read above. I set up a test project using the Libgdx setup tool, to see if there is a problem with java not being in the classpath, and I do not get the error...

Answer (score 1):

Go to Run tab -> Edit Configurations. Under Application, find DesktopLauncher and point it to the right Main class.

Comment: Maybe clear all the other Application launch configurations? It could be trying to run something else.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

1. Under "Build" menu click on "Rebuild Project".
2. Under "Run" menu click on "Edit configuration" -> delete the profile. 
   Then add back the profile ("Application" if it's a Java application by clicking on plus mark at left top corner), choose your main class from the "Main Class" drop-down menu.
3. Then build your project using, "Build" menu -> "Rebuild Project".